# composer installed.json" does not contain valid JSON

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I upgraded laravel 5.4 to laravel 5.5 according to the official documents, and then executed composer update, which returned this error

```
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.3.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.10.3): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.10.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (6.5.14): Extracting archive
  - Installing predis/predis (v1.1.7): Extracting archive
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
Package mtdowling/cron-expression is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use dragonmantank/cron-expression instead.
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files


  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "/home/vagrant/work/exports-api/vendor/composer/installed.json" does not co
  ntain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:

  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Then I'll check the file "/home/vagrant/work/exports-api/vendor/composer/installed.json" It's a blank, nothing
**Supplementary notes**
Before the update, there was something in installed.json, and composer update became blank. Now, the composer operation under this project will return this error

Comment: I'd delete (or rename) the file and run the composer command again. This should re-create the file.

Comment: @shaedrich I tried to delete vendor and rerun composer install, but the problem still exists

Comment: And what happens if you run `composer install` instead?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which version of Composer are you using?

Comment: @shaedrich The same as the error in the article，This error occurs after generating optimized autoload files

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for your reminding. The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

I changed the composer version from 2.0 to 1.0 to solve the problem

Comment: Remember that this is not a good long-term solution, as Composer v1 is EOL and packagist.org will not provide all packages for that version any more (see https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/)